# Reading and writing specific line from csv file in Kotlin

Tags: android, csv, kotlin

I wanted to read and write specific lines from a CSV file.

Here is an example of my CSV

```
ID; Code; Name
1; ABHD; Paul
2; HYDR; Arthur
3; POAJ; Jake
4; PLMH; Georges
```

Actually I know how to read all the file and put it into a list of lines by myFile.readLines().

But I want to read a specific line like the line with the Code ABHD, and later on modify that specific Line without reading and writing the whole file. Any idea ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/csv-files

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is a not a database. You can't write individual elements inside the file. You need to read the entire file and write the entire file. If the file is a reasonable size, you can read the entire file into memory, alter the data you want to change (in memory) and then write the entire file again. If the file is huge, you probably need to make your modifications "on the fly" (ie: read a line, (optionally) change it, write the line to the output file).

There are libraries that you can use to parse the data, as CSV can be complicated to parse (especially if it contains text strings).

See https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/csv-files for some help or search for "kotlin csv parse"